# mod_rewrite: multi-level URL using a request parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vanity-url

I currently have this set up and working fine inside a users folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?i=$1
```

e.g 127.0.0.1/site/users/admin goes to 127.0.0.1/site/users/index.php?i=admin

Now as this is for a profile page, how would i do something such as this.

users/admin/activity

So that it would show the activity page for that user? I am totally confused on how i would go about this.

Would it be best to make the index.php accept a page $_GET variable? But the how would i get htaccess to work around it?

Comment: Does really `users/admin` get redirected to `index.php?i=admin` or rather to `index.php?i=users/admin`? Also, did I understand correctly you'd like to have `activity` in another `$_GET` variable sent to index.php?

Comment: I updated my post so it is easier to understand, but yes users/admin goes to users/index.php?i=admin. And for your second question it depends, do you think that would be the best way to split the pages up? for example if you had a profile on my website it would be users/Havelock. Now if i wanted to see your friends i'd like to be able to use users/Havelock/Friends. Would it be best to have the second part go to another $_GET variable? so the out come would be users/index.php?i=Havelock&page=Friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rules will look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ index.php?i=$1&page=$2  [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?i=$1  [L]
```

Now your index.php should be getting 2 `$_GET` variables, `i` and `page`.

Comment: this works great! But when i use users/admin/friends all the CSS fails. But i directly linked to them and is working again (http://www.127.0.0.1/site/css/main.css rather than ../css/main.css) Do i have to do this for all my links?

Comment: @Trendee this is because you have relative links to you css, you can try adding `<base href="/site/css">` or something appropiate to the header of your pages..

Comment: is it okay to just include the full link?

Comment: @Trendee Yes, you can include the full link. It gets appended to the beginning of all the relative URLs that you have on that page.

Comment: I mean rather than adding <base> could i just include the full url on the stylesheet?

Comment: @Trendee sure, adding the `<base>` tag simply does it for the entire page, and is sometimes preferable because headers are sometimes generated by a single file, so it's 1 change. It doesn't matter how you do it.