# GET Multilevel Parameter with nice URIs through .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just found several similar questions about this topic but not the right one for my specific problem so here i go:

I would like to work with Nice URIs but it is necessary that i get at least one more parameter through the url.

my current .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

i tried this from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179054/mod-rewrite-multi-level-url-using-a-request-parameter)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ index.php?i=$1&page=$2  [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?i=$1  [L]
```

but something weird happens to my relative pathes. I tried using the  tag to adjust my paths but this also didn't work as expected.

My aim is to have URIs like websitexy.com/ship/12.

**Is there any way to rewrite the url in a way that doesn't mess the relative paths up like the previous one?**

Greetings.

Comment: Rewrite rule is not messing up your relative paths. It is your pretty URL scheme like `/ship/12` that is making your relative URLs to beecome `/ship/css/style.css` instead of `/css/style.css`

Comment: Best solution is to always use absolute URLs for these pretty URL schemes.

Comment: okay, i guess that is the simplest and cleanest idea. Thanks.